# Advice on vectorising code (by removing loop) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe that I've populated with data;

One column is the year that the measurement took place (meas_year).
Another column is reference data that I want to compare my measurement to (ref_year).

The issue is that we don't have reference data for every year.

Where we don't have reference data for the measurement, I want to take reference data from a previous year and adjust it so a valid comparison can still be done. This adjustment is done by summing up the adjustment values for the missing years. e.g. if the measurement happened in 2016 but we only have 2014 reference data, we need to add on the known adjustment for 2014 and 2015.

My question revolves how to do this checking and then how to select the right adjustment.

I have a dictionary (converted to a series) with the correct adjustment values like so:

```
adj_values={2014: 10.,
            2015: 12., 
            2016: 14.}
```

What I then do is:

find where the reference year is not equal to the measurement year

```
find=(np.where(data['ref_year'] != data['meas_year']))[0]
```

take the ref and meas years where they are not equal

```
reference_years=indexed_data['ref_year'].iloc[find]
measurement_years=indexed_data['meas_year'].iloc[find]
```

loop over all the data points and find which adjustment values need to be used and then add them up

```
for i in range(len(find)):
    find_adjustment=((adj_values.index >= int(reference_years[i])) & (adj_values.index < int(measurement_years[i])))
    adjustment=adj_values[find_adjustment].sum()
```

This all works but is there a faster solution?

Edit:

Here's some sample code with the expected output.

```
meas_years = pd.Series([2010, 2010, 2012, 2016, 2016])
ref_years = pd.Series([2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011])

adj_values_dict={2010: 5,
                 2011: 12,
                 2012: 14,
                 2013: 4,
                 2014: 2,
                 2015: 5, 
                 2016: 7}

adj_values=pd.Series(adj_values_dict)
adjustment=pd.Series(np.zeros(len(meas_years)))


find=(np.where(ref_years != meas_years))[0]
meas_years_subset=meas_years.iloc[find]
ref_years_subset=ref_years.iloc[find]


for i in range(len(find)):
    find_adjustment=((adj_values.index >= ref_years[find[i]]) & (adj_values.index < meas_years[find[i]]))    
    adjustment.iloc[find[i]]=adj_values[find_adjustment].sum()
```

This should give:

```
In [24]: adjustment
Out[24]: 
0     0
1     0
2    17
3    37
4    37
```

Comment: Can you please shorten this to your dataframe and expected output dataframe please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using DataFrames instead of Series, and use `.apply()` with a lambda expression to do the job:

```
adj_values_dict={2010: 5,
                 2011: 12,
                 2012: 14,
                 2013: 4,
                 2014: 2,
                 2015: 5, 
                 2016: 7}

adj_values=pd.Series(adj_values_dict)


meas_years = [2010, 2010, 2012, 2016, 2016]
ref_years = [2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011]
years = pd.DataFrame({'meas':meas_years,'ref':ref_years})

years['adjustment'] = years.apply(lambda x: adj_values.loc[min(x.meas,x.ref):max(x.meas,x.ref)-1].sum(),
                                  axis='columns')
print(years)
```

Output:

```
.  meas   ref  adjustment
0  2010  2010           0
1  2010  2010           0
2  2012  2010          17
3  2016  2011          37
4  2016  2011          37
```

Note that `.loc[start:end]` will return all the values between the specified start/end indexes. I use `min()` and `max()` functions but if the you are sure to verify at any time *ref < meas* you could just pick the right value at the right place : `adj_values.loc[x.ref:x.meas-1].sum()`

In terms of performance:

- Your code : `200 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop`
- With DF : `200 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop`

Comment: Sorry I maybe explained badly but I'm using a dataframe (as stated at the start) but then pull out the different data into series. The issue is that I have tens of thousands of data points and I thought there should be a way to vectorise that horrible loop.

Comment: Ok, maybe you could try something like numba or cython to enhance pandas performances.